# Environment env.getproperty is not working

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, configuration

I have a problem with Environment env.getproperty, env not find local properties, but it find system properties. I dont know about this so much and I need to solve it. Please, help me.
Attached my code and its configuration.

Controllers.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to 
    configure as beans -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mret.client.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mret.client.security" />
<context:property-placeholder   location="classpath*:paremeters.properties" />
```

Paremeters.properties:

```
url.services.search=http://localhost:8080/mretcore/search
url.services.orderdetail=http://localhost:8080/mretcore/orderdetail?orderid=
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class OrdersController {
RestClient restClient = new RestClientImpl();
@Autowired
private Environment env;
String url = env.getProperty("url.services.search");
etc....}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Doe.png)

Comment: Moved to answer...

Answer (score 0):

1. property-placeholder does not place properties into env. It is for variables set on OS level.
2. better use System.getProperty("property_name") which includes env, JVM properties, -D properties passed into java command line and yes - those from property-placeholder.
3. Also you may consider to use your url as bean property and do not get it explicitly, but by spring bean property definition like `${url.services.search}` 
   instead of having property name in code. After time it may hard to find where what property loaded. It is better approach...